# Javascript - Display images from photo into unique <div>

Tags: javascript, html

I have been searching this site for days looking for a solution. I would like to use javascript to take images from a folder on my server and put them into a set of  like this. I thought it would be fairly simple but I've come up with nothing.

It would take the place of the divs below between the section tags in this code.

I could just hard code them all but there are 107 images that I need to display in this carousel and it would be much easier in the long run to be able to add/delete images from the folder than to do so by having to hard code them all.
Below is the code I have so far.

```
<section id="vendors" class="zerogrid">
        <div width="90%" >
            <div class="container" width="90%" style="background-color: #858585;">
            <h2 class="clr-1" style="padding: 2%;" >Our Suppliers</h2>
            <section class="customer-logos slider" style="padding-bottom: 5%;">

                <div class="slide"><img src="images/image1.png"></div>
                <div class="slide"><img src="images/image2.png"></div>
                <div class="slide"><img src="images/image3.png"></div>

            </section>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.customer-logos').slick({
                slidesToShow: 6,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 1000,
                arrows: false,
                dots: false,
                    pauseOnHover: true,
                    responsive: [{
                    breakpoint: 768,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 106
                    }
                }, {
                    breakpoint: 520,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 3
                    }
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>
    </section>
```

This carousel works fine, sp any help getting the  thing sorted would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've been tweaking this code a bit

Answer (score 0):

Add id by:

`<section class="customer-logos slider" style="padding-bottom: 5%;" id="customer-logos-slider">`

And add this to your script tag:

```
window.onload = function () {
    let toAdd = '';
    let totalImages = 107;
    for (let i = 0; i < totalImages; i++) {
        toAdd += '<div class="slide"><img src="images/image' + i + '.png"></div>';
    }
    document.getElementById('customer-logos-slider').innerHTML = toAdd;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tony, But no go. I get nothing displaying. maybe this "simple thing" isn't as simple as I thought it would be. Thanks for the time and code anyway.

Comment: The image display gives me broken link placeholders. Also i fear that it's going to display them all out in a long stack. which I don't want to have happen. Optimally they would display in the <div> section and the code below turns them into a carousel. I have my towel at the ready to throw at this point. :)

Comment: If you demonstrate your problem by sharing similar code on codepen.io, we may be able to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with this bit of code. It is placing image placeholders but all of them are displaying at one time and not is separate divs. Also the 5th line of code that is setting each image with a number. I would like the javascript to pull the file name from each image in the folder, place it in a div (similar to line 6) and then repeat it the end of the images.

````
<script type="text/javascript">
              window.onload = function () {
                  let toAdd = '';
                  let totalImages = 107;
                  for (let i = 0; i < totalImages; i++) {
                  toAdd += '<div class="slide"><img src="images/vendors/' + i + '.jpg"></div>';
                  }
                   document.getElementById('logos').innerHTML = toAdd;
                 }

      </script>```

This last iteration of the tinkering leaves me with a large space in the section that contains nothing but I am guessing it's loading empty files due to the numbering. Any other thoughts from anyone?
````